# ionic serve command fails with "build dev failed: Cannot find module '../util/Logger'"

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, node-modules, serve

I create and run an ionic project using

```
ionic start test1 blank --v2
cd test1
ionic serve
```

And I get:

```
[13:48:30]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.42 
[13:48:30]  watch started ... 
[13:48:30]  build dev started ... 
[13:48:30]  clean started ... 
[13:48:30]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[13:48:30]  copy started ... 
[13:48:30]  transpile started ... 
[13:48:34]  transpile finished in 4.04 s 
[13:48:34]  webpack started ... 
[13:48:34]  build dev failed: Cannot find module '../util/Logger' 
[13:48:35]  copy finished in 4.13 s 
[13:48:35]  watch ready in 4.14 s
```

I tried to remove the node-modules directory and make "npm install" to rebuild the modules, but with the same result. (even reinstalled ionic framefork)

I have a Linux Mint 18.

Comment: I found this github issue, apparently you can solve the problem by changing the 'Logger' module name to 'logger': https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/326

Comment: Yes, that solves it!